# How to load custom font with typesafe css?

Tags: css, tornadofx

I want to load a custom font in a tornadofx-app with typesafe css, is this possible?
Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Hi! There is no special support for @font-face rules at the moment, but we're working on it. For now you can override the `render()` function of your stylesheet and add `"@font-face { ... }" + super.render()`. We'll tune back in with a better solution asap :)

Answer (score 5):

As long as a font is loaded, it can be used in CSS, so we've added a `loadFont` helper in TornadoFX that can be used like so:

```kotlin
class FontTest : App(Main::class, Styles::class)

class Main : View("Font Test") {
    override val root = stackpane {
        label("This is my Label") {
            addClass(Styles.custom)
        }
    }
}

class Styles : Stylesheet() {
    companion object {
        val custom by cssclass()
        // Note that loadFont() returns Font?
        val riesling = loadFont("/fonts/riesling.ttf", 48.0)
    }

    init {
        custom {
            padding = box(25.px)
            riesling?.let { font = it }
            // or if you just want to set the font family:
            // riesling?.let { fontFamily = it.family }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If you know for sure the font exists (e.g. you're including in your build), that can be simplified to:

```kotlin
class Styles : Stylesheet() {
    companion object {
        val custom by cssclass()
        val riesling = loadFont("/fonts/riesling.ttf", 48.0)!!
    }
    
    init {
        custom {
            padding = box(25.px)

            font = riesling
            // or if you just want to set the font family:
            // fontFamily = riesling.family
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Edvin and Ruckus T-Boom, thanks for your quick help. It works good for me. With TornadoFx you make a great work.

Answer (score 2):

By the way since 29 days as [Ruckus T-Boom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2094298/ruckus-t-boom) answered this question he added the `loadFont` function :) , with which it's possible to write:

```
class Styles : Stylesheet() {
    private val customFont = loadFont("/fonts/custom-font.ttf", 14)!!

    init {
        root {
            font = customFont
            fontSize = 11.px
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I never came back to fix my answer, so I just did.